# Typesetting an optimisation problem with numerous constraints

Tags: math-mode, equations, formatting

I am writing an optimisation problem with 50 constraints. My code is below.

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
{\underset{x_{i}}{\textnormal{minimise}}} \quad  
&800\left(\sum_{i=1}^{89}x_i\right)+99\left(x_{34}+x_{81}\right)  \\
\mathllap{\text{subject to} \quad} 
&x_{11}+x{12}\geq 1 \\
&x_{13}+x{14}\geq 1 \\
&x_{18}+x{19}\geq 1 \\
....
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

For convenience, I have denoted the remaining constraints by the ellipsis "...". For some reason, the whole optimisation problem begins on a new page once the contraints reach the bottom of the existing page. Not only this, but the constraints that do not fit on this single page are not displayed.

Is there a way to intelligently format this optimisation problem?

**Edit**

I am using the packages

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
```

Comment: Have you tried inserting the instruction `\allowdisplaybreaks` before `begin{equation*}`?

Comment: Off-topic: What's the purpose of the `\mathllap` "wrapper"? I'd get rid of it.

Comment: @Mico I tried `\allowdisplaybreaks`, but it did not work (does it require a particular package?) I removed `\mathllap` (I took that from a previous example that I wrote using `rcases`).

Comment: Please clarify what "it did not work" entails. `\allowdisplaybreaks` is a macro provided by the `amsmath` package -- the same package that provides the `equation*` and `aligned` environments. The purpose of `\allowdisplaybreaks` is to, well, allow page breaks in multi-line displayed equation environments. (As you've discovered, such page breaks are not allowed by default.)

Comment: I don't know about your other code, but here `\mathllap` does nothing except create code clutter.

Comment: @Mico Apologies for not being specific. There was no change in my document after I inserted `\allowdisplaybreaks` before `\begin{equation*}`. That is, it did not change anything.

Comment: @Mico I have edited my original post, including the packages that I am using in my document. As for the the `equation*` itself, this has been copied and pasted into my post. The only difference is that I have left out all of the constraints for simplicity (in my post I have included the first three constraints, namely: `x_{11}+x{12}\geq 1`, `x_{13}+x{14}\geq 1`, and `x_{18}+x{19}\geq 1` ... I did not think it would be necesary to include all 50 constraints).

Comment: Please see the answer I posted a short while ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `\allowdisplaybreaks`, provided by the `amsmath` package, is supposed to allow page breaks inside multi-line diplayed equations. However, as is explained in subsection 3.9, "Vertical spacing and page breaks in multiline displays", of the user guide of the `amsmath` package, `\allowdisplaybreaks` does not operate on the contents of `split`, `aligned`, `gathered`, and `alignedat` environments.

To fix this, I suggest you place all equations in a single `align*` environment instead of nesting an `aligned` environment inside an `equation*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % choose a suitable document class
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%% Sets page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,
    %top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,
    margin=2.5cm,
    marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

%\usepackage{amsmath}  % is loaded automatically by 'mathtools'
%\usepackage{amsfonts} % is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% \usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode} % I don't have this package

\begin{document}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{align*}
\underset{x_{i}}{\textnormal{minimise}}\quad  
&800\biggl(\,\sum_{i=1}^{89}x_i\biggr)+99(x_{34}+x_{81})  \\
\textnormal{subject to} \quad
&x_{11}+x_{12}\geq 1 \\
&x_{13}+x_{14}\geq 1 \\
&x_{18}+x_{19}\geq 1 \\
&\dots
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked brilliantly. My optimisation problem does not begin on a new page and all constraints are displayed over multiple pages. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let me mention there exists a dedicated package: `optidef`, which defines several optimisation environments, with various layouts, which accept a `<b>` optional argument to break the environment across pages. Here is  a code using the `mini*` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm, marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{optidef} % dedicated package

\begin{document}

\begin{mini*}<b>
{x_{i}}{800\biggl(\,\sum_{i=1}^{89}x_i\biggr)+99(x_{34}+x_{81})}
  {}{}
\addConstraint{x_{11}+x_{12}\geq 1}
\addConstraint{x_{13}+x_{14}\geq 1}
\addConstraint{x_{18}+x_{19}\geq 1}
\addConstraint{\dots\dots\dots\dots}
\end{mini*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to write multiple arguments under the minimize, e.g. as asked for in a previous [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571194/is-it-possible-to-use-substack-with-textnormal-in-an-align-environment?noredirect=1#comment1439264_571194)

Comment: yes, you type what you want for the first argument of the environment. You might try with `\substack{... \\...}`, for instance.

Comment: This is truly a great package. One last question: I am having trouble aligning the `\geq` signs. Instead of aligning the beginning of each contraint with the beginning of the objective function, is it possible to align the `\geq` signs of the constraints?

Comment: Yes: instead of `\addConstraint{x_{11}+x_{12}\geq 1}`, &c., write `\addConstraint{x_{11}+x_{12}}{\geq 1}`. You can see more possibilities, in §6 of the documentation, pp. 8-9: *Output Formats for the Constraints*.