# Is it possible to use `\substack` with `\textnormal` in an `align*` environment?

Tags: math-mode, align

I am trying to write multiple lines underneath my minimisation problem in an `align*` environment. This can be achieved by using the command `\min_{\substack{x_{j} \\ j=1,...,70}}`, which produces the following output

[image]

I would like to write minimisation, as opposed to min. However, the command `\textnormal{minimise}_{\substack{x_{j} \\ j=1,...,70}}` does not produce the required output. How can this be achieved?

Comment: The number of left and right curly braces in your expression don't match.

Comment: @inavda This should now be fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Off-topic: I would replace `j=1,...,70` with `j=1,\dots,70` in order to get a proper typographic ellipse.

Comment: @Mico Appreciate the suggestion! :)

Answer (score 2):

From some quick experimentation, using `\operatorname*` instead of `\textnormal` seems to do the trick.